# Combine Array value with same key

Tags: java, android, arrays, dictionary, hashmap

I have a list which hold all my data: `setData`

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> setData = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();
Map<String, Integer> set;
```

and the value are added like this (this happens in a loop, when it is iterating through a cursor):

```
set = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
set.put("value", value);
set.put("day", day);
setData.add(set);
```

The Array is sorted **afterwards**, from the lowest value for 'day' to the highest value for 'day'.

**My question:** I want to combine all 'values' with the same 'day', the 'value' need to be added or subtracted, that my final Array only holds one value for each day.

Comment: Seems like a complex structure. Did you consider using SQLite?

Comment: Can you combine the values while you are populating the original struct, or you have to do it later? On the other hand, if you are going to store a "value" and a "day" values ALWAYS in every HashMap, then you are making an improper use of it. Just define a JavaBeans class with those two attributes.

Comment: Why do you need a list of hashes, when all day will be unique in the end?

Comment: @DoctororDrive Nope, I need it as a Array (or something which function similar).

Comment: @thelawnmowerman Yep, I can.

Comment: @thelawnmowerman Wait, I can't, because the Array is sorted afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> dayValue = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
 for(Map<String, Integer> set : setData) {
     int day = set.get("day"); 
     int value = set.get("value");
     int storedValue = dayValue.get(day);
     // do your addition or subtraction with value and storedValue,
     // and update the map after that
     dayValue.put(day, storedValue);
 }
```

Thus, for each day, you will have **a** value. No need to use `array` in this case, since you want to keep a value for each `unique` day, `hashmap` is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, leaving the unnecessary field out:

```
set = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

In every cycle:

```
if (set.containsKey(day))
{
  value += set.get(day);
} 

set.put(day, value);
```

This way you will have a hash with one values per day.

Comment: Very nice idea, but I guess it won't work in my case, because the Array is sorted after the insert, dependant on on the day value (from low to high).